# Remove duplicates in a JavaScript object array and sum the entries

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, plotly

I have an object with two properties: `x` and `y`, of types String and number respectively.

The corresponding (x,y) values are used to plot a time series using Plotly in an Express.js application, with `x` taking the format `2013-10-04T22:23`.

Now say I have an object with **duplicate** `x` values, and I need to **remove** the duplicates, leaving only one entry for that `x` value and sum up the corresponding `y` values, again leaving only one corresponding `y` value.

For example:

```
var data = [
               {
                   x: ["2013-10-04 22:22", "2013-10-04 22:22", "2013-10-04 22:22", 
                       "2013-12-12 15:15"],
                   y: [1, 1, 1, 6]
               }
           ];
```

I want to sum up the `y` values for the `2013-10-04 22:22` `x` values, leaving only one `x` value `y` value pair like so:

```
data = [
           {
               x: ["2013-10-04 22:22", 
                   "2013-12-12 15:15"],
               y: [3, 6]
           }
       ];
```

How would one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that receives an object and manipulate the object the way you want:

```
const obj = {
  x: ["2013-10-04 22:22", "2013-10-04 22:22", "2013-10-04 22:22", "2013-12-12 15:15"],
  y: [1, 1, 1, 6]
}

function removeObjDuplicates ({ x, y }) {

  const occurrences = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      occurrences[x[i]] = (occurrences[x[i]] || 0) + y[i];
  }

  return {
    x:  Object.keys(occurrences),
    y:  Object.values(occurrences),
  }
}
```

**removeObjDuplicates(obj)** will return:

```
{
   x: ["2013-10-04 22:22", "2013-12-12 15:15"],
   y: [3, 6]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.